# Insert statement running very slowly on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I had been getting data from production and loading it into a staging DWH. And then loading it further into usable format later in another DWH from staging.

Both staging and the final DWH are on the same server. This process wasn't taking long before, but now it's taking ages to load the data from staging. It takes a few minutes to load data from production into staging, but it takes hours to load it further and I am not sure why.

FYI: I had been testing the loads, so I have truncated/deleted the table a few times and reloaded them

Also I had a non clustered index on one of the columns in actual DWH which I removed

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_EncounterTB_Encounter_id] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Encounter_id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [Uniq_EncounterTB_Encounter_table_id] 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Encounter_Table_id] ASC)
```

Below is the table structure for staging and I have removed a few of the columns:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stg_Encounter]
(
    [encntr_id] [float] NOT NULL,
    [person_id] [float] NOT NULL,
    [visit_id_stay_number] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [mrn] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [encntr_type_cd] [float] NULL,
    [reg_dt_tm] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [disch_dt_tm] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [admit_cd] [float] NULL,
    [visit_cd] [float] NULL,
    [source_cd] [float] NULL,
    [sepearation_cd] [float] NULL,
    [medical_service_cd] [float] NULL,
    [reason_problem] [varchar](1000) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

For the actual DWH, the table structure is as below :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Encounter]
(
    [Encounter_Table_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Encounter_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Person_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Visit_ID] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [MRN] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Encounter_Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Arrival_Dt_Tm] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Departure_Dt_Tm] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Mode_of_Arrival] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Visit_Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Admit_Source] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Mode_of_Separation] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Medical_Service] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Presenting_Problem] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [LOAD_Dt_Tm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Data_Source] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_EncounterTB_Encounter_id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Encounter_id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Below insert is being used for inserting data :

```
INSERT INTO [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Encounter] 
        (
[Encounter_Table_id]
  ,[Encounter_id]
  ,[Person_id]
  ,[Visit_ID]
  ,[MRN]
  ,[Encounter_Type]
  ,[Arrival_Dt_Tm]
  ,[Departure_Dt_Tm]
  ,[Mode_of_Arrival]
  ,[Visit_Type]
  ,[Admit_Source]
  ,[Mode_of_Separation]
  ,[Medical_Service]
  ,[Presenting_Problem]
  ,[MSAU_LOAD_Dt_Tm]
  ,[Data_Source]    
    )
SELECT
[Encounter_Table_id]= CONVERT(INT,Stg_e.[encntr_id])
    ,   [Encounter_id]                      = CONVERT(INT,Stg_e.[encntr_id])
  ,[Person_id]                          = CONVERT(INT,Stg_e.[person_id])
  ,[Visit_ID]                           = Stg_e.[visit_id_stay_number]
  ,[MRN]                                = Stg_e.[mrn]
  ,[Encounter_Type]                     = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[emr_get_code_Description](Stg_e.encntr_type_cd)
  ,[Arrival_Dt_Tm]                      = CONVERT(DATETIME,Stg_e.reg_dt_tm)
  ,[Departure_Dt_Tm]                    = CONVERT(DATETIME,Stg_e.disch_dt_tm)
  ,[Mode_of_Arrival]                    = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.admit_cd)
  ,[Visit_Type]                         = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.visit_cd)
  ,[Admit_Source]                       = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.source_cd)
  ,[Mode_of_Separation]                 = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.sepearation_cd)
  ,[Medical_Service]                    = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.medical_service_cd)
  ,[Presenting_Problem]                 = Stg_e.reason_problem
  ,[MSAU_LOAD_Dt_Tm]                    = getdate()
  ,[Data_Source]                        = 'SourceName'



    FROM [dbo].Stg_Encounter Stg_e
    where NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].Encounter e
                            WHERE stg_e.encntr_id = e.encounter_id)
```

The function used is as per below :

```
USE [ACTUAL_DWH]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[Description](@cv int)  
returns varchar(80)  
as begin   

declare @ret varchar(80)  
select @ret = cv.DESCRIPTION
from ACTUAL_DWH.DBO.CODE_VALUE cv   
where cv.code_value = @cv   
    and cv.active_ind = 1  
return isnull(@ret, 0)

end;
```

I am just confused where I have missed stuff!!! And what can I change. the table has around 6 million rows and it was loading them in a minute.

After the suggestions provided, I got to know that issue is with the function that I am using.I have read about CROSS APPLY but is it a good idea to apply CROSS APPLY on 15 columns?

Comment: FYI: I would be very surprised if anyone can assist based on this information. Database performance beyond the basics is a very specialised area and frequently involves quite a lot of investigation. It could easily be that you've crossed an internal threshold which changes the entire query. If you look at the expected and actual execution plans you might get a hint of what is causing the poor performance.

Comment: Start with identifying the bottleneck (if not yet). For example, replace insert into with select sum(1), so you'll see if it's query calculation or insertion. I bet it's related to your function, but let us know about what you got.

Comment: As already mentioned, you need to break your code down into the smallest possible piece that exhibits the issue (i.e. seperate the insert from the select). You can also attack it from the other direction - install `sp_whoisactive` and check the waits. But that will probably just take you back to optimising queries anyway

Comment: Thanks Everyone!!! I needed advice on what I should be looking into and wasn't sure what more details should I be posting. I'll try the suggestions provided and will be back with the results.

Comment: I have been trying a few things, one of which being :  if I remove all the functions and run the insert with the select statement, it returns almost in a minute which is other wise taking ages to run. I am using a very simple function and I am not sure what I should be changing to get it to run quicker.

Comment: Also, there are almost 15 rows on which I apply this function. I have read about CROSS APPLY. But it doesn't seem to be a good idea in this scenario. I have actually created another similar function as well. And they have made my query way slower!!! Any other alternatives?

Comment: Is production under load while you are attempting this insert? Could be much more difficult to acquire the same kinds of locks in a busy environment.

Comment: No there is no issue with Production. And we are actually not directly connecting to PROD but a ready only mirrored copy of PROD that we have on another server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL CREATE INDEX Statement to retrieve data from the database very fast.

```
    CREATE INDEX IX_Encounter
            ON [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Encounter](Encounter_Table_id) ON [PRIMARY]

    INSERT INTO [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Encounter] 
            (
    [Encounter_Table_id]
      ,[Encounter_id]
      ,[Person_id]
      ,[Visit_ID]
      ,[MRN]
      ,[Encounter_Type]
      ,[Arrival_Dt_Tm]
      ,[Departure_Dt_Tm]
      ,[Mode_of_Arrival]
      ,[Visit_Type]
      ,[Admit_Source]
      ,[Mode_of_Separation]
      ,[Medical_Service]
      ,[Presenting_Problem]
      ,[MSAU_LOAD_Dt_Tm]
      ,[Data_Source]    
        )
    SELECT
    [Encounter_Table_id]= CONVERT(INT,Stg_e.[encntr_id])
        ,   [Encounter_id]                      = CONVERT(INT,Stg_e.[encntr_id])
      ,[Person_id]                          = CONVERT(INT,Stg_e.[person_id])
      ,[Visit_ID]                           = Stg_e.[visit_id_stay_number]
      ,[MRN]                                = Stg_e.[mrn]
      ,[Encounter_Type]                     = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[emr_get_code_Description](Stg_e.encntr_type_cd)
      ,[Arrival_Dt_Tm]                      = CONVERT(DATETIME,Stg_e.reg_dt_tm)
      ,[Departure_Dt_Tm]                    = CONVERT(DATETIME,Stg_e.disch_dt_tm)
      ,[Mode_of_Arrival]                    = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.admit_cd)
      ,[Visit_Type]                         = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.visit_cd)
      ,[Admit_Source]                       = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.source_cd)
      ,[Mode_of_Separation]                 = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.sepearation_cd)
      ,[Medical_Service]                    = [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].[Description](Stg_e.medical_service_cd)
      ,[Presenting_Problem]                 = Stg_e.reason_problem
      ,[MSAU_LOAD_Dt_Tm]                    = getdate()
      ,[Data_Source]                        = 'SourceName'



        FROM [dbo].Stg_Encounter Stg_e
        where NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM [ACTUAL_DWH].[dbo].Encounter e
                                WHERE stg_e.encntr_id = e.encounter_id)
```

You can check more info about index here.[INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)

Comment: Hi Unknown. I am asking a completely different question. :) I know about the indexes.

Comment: Ooops sorry my mistake. Wrong understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this post. As suggested I had tried to break down the query and found that the function was the culprit. I am exploring it further for the resolution.

The function is taking parameter and running a SQL on another table. Which is slowing down the query. If I do the insert without the function it actually takes a few seconds to load 6 million rows.